# Is it advisable to use three separate channel in a RGB image to extract feature with CNN?

Tags: image, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to extract features from CIFAR10 dataset using autoencoder. But it's not giving good accuracy when I use those features. Should I try to use grayscale images or Continue with RGB images?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon your application.

If your application requires extracting features for something like object detection then keep the colours.

But if your work is something related to sharpening, smoothening or some sort of image-processing( Morphological, Segmentation ) then greyscale might help.

Comment: Yes, I want features for image classification.

Comment: You might have to tune the parameters in order to get better results. The default parameters would usually not give accurate results.